# How to execute after no input happend for some time

Tags: java, swing, time

I am trying to achieve the following behavior:

You press a button which toggles through multiple elements (in swing). The point is, that a message or whatever should only appear if no toggle happened in the last second. That means you press `button1`, wait one second, then comes the message you pressed `button1`; and if you press `button1`, then (under one second) press `button2`, the message should say `button2` was pressed.

I found some timer stuff like this (as i know now, this is a android example. perhaps there is something similar to this for swing??):

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Do something after 1000ms
  }
}, 1000);
```

How could I stop the task? I don't need any code, just a hint.

Comment: pass thread an instance of a class that implements runnable, have that class have a variable that you check in your run() to see if it may execute whatever you want to do.

Comment: unfortunately i do not really understand this :(
u mean i should run a thread only for "sending the message", have a boolean that only gets setted if the last press is one second ago? that would be not really performant i think.

Answer (score 2):

For code

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runIt = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
  //Do something after 1000ms
  }
}
handler.postDelayed(runIt, 1000);
```

you can delete message from queue by

```
handler.removeCallbacks(runIt);
```

Comment: am i missing something? the handler class has no functions like postDelayed(). is this for andriod? i need it for java swing... should have say that.
and the handler class is a class for logging purpose i think

Comment: whats a pitty :) 
hopefully somebody else can help me XD